# mysql query korean(Foreign language) word is broken

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

now i'm using spring framework + java + mysql(maria db)
when select query(for searching) was executed, there is no problem
but when search in korean (utf-8) word 
that word was broken

i think query has no problem because when searching in english or number
result is fine

this is my dispatcher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model (annotation true) -->
    <annotation-driven>
        <message-converters>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
            </beans:bean>
        </message-converters>
    </annotation-driven>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <resources mapping="/uploadImg/**" location="/uploadImg/" />
    <resources mapping="/UploadFile/**" location="/UploadFile/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="order" value="1"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="viewClass">
            <beans:value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-*.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ex.biz" />

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="com.ex.biz.intercepter.InterCepterCheck"/>       
    </interceptors>


</beans:beans>
```

and this is mybatis-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/ex.properties" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${ex_driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${ex_url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${ex_username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${ex}"></property>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.ex.biz.dto"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config/mybatis.xml"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>




</beans>
```

what config should i modify??
if i Missed concepts could you let me know??
i'm confused now...

**when i searched '나나' executed query written 'ëë'**

thank you for helping me

Comment: Are you sure that encodings of database tables are set to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer
first of all i'm sure that my database tables are set as "utf-8"

i send data as GET
so tomcat server(in server.xml ) set URIEncoding

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

URIEncoding="UTF-8"

and then i solve the all problem

if you have problem like me.
you have to send data as POST.
Or send as GET and then put uriEcoding in server.xml

Comment: You can accept your own question. Click the *check* button.